# How do I assign shortcut keys to buttons on the bindingNavigator?

Tags: winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, bindingnavigator

Is there a way to assign shortcut keys to the standard navigation ToolStrip Items in a BindingNavigator?

The items that get added using the .AddStandardItems method are of type ToolStripItem which doesn't have a ShortcutKeys property.

I tried to cast to ToolStripMenuItem , but it fails.

```
 public void ConfigureMyNavigator()
    {
               // Adds ToolStripItems which don't support shortcut keys           
                m_navigator.AddStandardItems();

                // Adds a ToolStripMenuItem which can support a shortcut key
                var button = new ToolStripMenuItem
                {
                    Size = new Size(0, 0),
                    Text = "Save",
                    ShortcutKeys = (Keys)Shortcut.CtrlS,
                    ToolTipText = "Press Ctrl+S to save"
                };
                button.Click += tsmi_Click;

                m_navigator.Items.Add(button);

                //   This fails with invalid cast exception
                ((ToolStripMenuItem)m_navigator.Items[1]).ShortcutKeys = (Keys)Shortcut.AltLeftArrow;


    }
```

I guess I could replace the toolstripitems with toolstripmenuitems one by one, but feel this is rather awkward.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can listen for key commands and then raise the click of the appropriate ToolStripButton. Override the `ProcessCmdKey` method in your form code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case (Keys.Alt | Keys.Left):
            m_navigator.Items[1].PerformClick();
            break;
        case (Keys.Alt | Keys.Right):
            m_navigator.Items[6].PerformClick();
            break;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding "&" symbol in front of the button caption?

> Text = "&Save"

Comment: Hi Ankit. Good idea, but I want other keys than Alt.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the AddStandardItems method and overload the ToolStripMenuItem's constructor to accept ToolStripItem as a parameter for easier creation of the items.

But it's still sort of "replacing the items one by one".

Comment: Is there a way to override AddStandardItems and still retain the way the position text works?  At the moment I cant see how overriding is any better than simply not calling AddStandardItems - and adding the buttons one by one. In overriding AddStandardItems, I need to know how to hook the buttons up to the events, where to get the icons from, and how to make the record number text work the same way

Comment: it probably is not any better, it's just reusable